# What method is called when application appears from background on iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I know that when iphone application goes to background, these methods are called:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

what method(s) are called when application appears from background?

are there any methods in ViewController which are called?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Along with the `applicationDidBecomeActive:` and `applicationWillEnterForeground:` messages sent to the application delegate, the OS will also send corresponding `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` and `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` notifications.

You can have your view controller listen to these notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(appWillEnterForegroundNotification:) 
                                             name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

Don't forget to remove yourself as an observer before your view controller gets destroyed.

Comment: +1 OK I stand corrected. Burjua you need to use NSNotificationCenter and register your viewControllers to listen to those notifications :)

Answer (score 1):

```
– applicationDidBecomeActive:
– applicationWillEnterForeground:
```

Oops didnt read your question properly. These two methods are in the UIApplicationDelegate

```
– viewWillAppear:
– viewDidAppear:
```

And those are in UIViewController

Comment: Ok, thanks, anything in view controller? I'm looking for something similar to `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated and - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` ?

Comment: `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated and - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` aren't called unfortunately