# how to restart animation after screen is unlock

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

i use this to restart my animation after my app is enter foreground again.
it works fine when click home button and active app again.
but it does not work when screen unlock.

restartAnimation is executed, but i don't know while it does not work when screen unlock

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(restartAnimation)    
                                               name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

Comment: You may want to check out this link.  There are more than 1 way the iOS will exit and place in the background your app!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771015/what-method-is-called-when-application-appears-from-background-on-iphone

Comment: Also, have you tried placing an NSLog output in that routine you have above to see if it is being run at all from the 2nd (non-working) state you describe?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

For handling after unlock you have to add an observer to UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification